# Automatically Updating TreeView of Nested Items

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx, treeview, javafx-8

I have a Goal, which has a list of Objectives. An objective has a list of Strategies. A strategy has a list of Tactics. A tactic has a list of Tasks.

I want to be able to display this in a TreeView, and I want for the tree to be synchronized to the items. That is, if I delete an Objective, that Objective, along with its children, will disappear from the TreeView as well.

So far, this is what I have been trying.

```
/**
 * The base class for all PlanItems, which include ActionItems down to
 * ActionTasks, and Objectives down to Tasks.
 *
 * @author Toni-Tran
 */
public class PlanItem implements Comparable<PlanItem> {
    protected ObservableList<PlanItem> childPlanItems = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList();
    protected TreeItem<PlanItem> treeItem = new TreeItem<>(this);
```

This is the base class for all those items. In its constructor:

```
public PlanItem() {
    CustomBinding.bindLists(treeItem.getChildren(), childPlanItems, PlanItem::getTreeItem);
}
```

I am using my custom binding, which binds two lists of different objects together. (Alternatively, I could have used EasyBind).

```
/**
 * Binds a source list's elements to a destination list. Any changes made in
 * the source list will reflect in the destination list.
 *
 * @param <SRC> The source list's object type.
 * @param <DEST> The destination list's object type.
 * @param dest The destination list that will be bound to the src list.
 * @param src The source list to watch for changes, and propagate up to the
 * destination list.
 * @param transformer A function that will transform a source list data
 * type, A, into a destination list data type, B.
 */
public static <SRC extends Object, DEST extends Object> void bindLists(
        ObservableList<DEST> dest, ObservableList<SRC> src, Function<SRC, DEST> transformer) {
    /*Add the initial data into the destination list.*/
    for (SRC a : src) {
        dest.add(transformer.apply(a));
    }
    /*Watch for future data to add to the destination list. Also watch for removal
     of data form the source list to remove its respective item in the destination
     list.*/
    src.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends SRC> c) -> {
        while (c.next()) {
            /*Watch for removed data.*/
            if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                for (SRC a : c.getRemoved()) {
                    int from = c.getFrom();
                    dest.remove(from);
                }
            }
            /*Watch for added data.*/
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                for (SRC a : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                    int indexAdded = src.indexOf(a);
                    dest.add(indexAdded, transformer.apply(a));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach. The list of child items is usually a list of objects that EXTEND PlanItem, rather than just PlanItem itself. Shouldn't it be an `ObservableList<? extends PlanItem>` then? Doing so makes the rest of my code complicated.

The plan is to create a TreeItem that wraps the PlanItem. Then, synchronize the TreeItem's child TreeItems to the PlanItem's child PlanItems. This repeats recursively for each nested PlanItem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bindLists` method is quite general, and can be written (as you have it now) without any reference to the lists you're working with right now (i.e. without reference to the `PlanItem` class). So I would probably just make it

```
public static <SRC, DEST> void bindLists(ObservableList<DEST> dest, ObservableList<SRC> src, ...) { ... }
```

Note though that the mapping function just has to be able to apply to the elements of `src` (so it has to act on things of which the elements of `src` are a type) and produce something that can be placed into the `dest` list. So using `Function<SRC, DEST>` is probably too restrictive. Try

```
public static <SRC, DEST> void bindLists(ObservableList<DEST> dest, ObservableList<SRC> src, 
     Function<? super SRC, ? extends DEST> transformer) { ... }
```

Now you can call

```
bindLists(ObservableList<TreeItem<PlanItem>>, ObservableList<T>, PlanItem::getTreeItem)
```

where `T` is `PlanItem` *or any subclass*, and it should be easy to use.

Comment: Why do I have to give the function parameters a lower bound? Why not extends?

Comment: The function you actually want to pass in is a `Function<PlanItem, TreeItem<PlanItem>>` (because you're defining it in the `PlanItem` class, taking `this -> new TreeItem<>(...)`.) If that's to act on an element, say of an `ObservableList<Goal>` then the parameter type for the function (`PlanItem`) is a superclass of the actual value you're giving it (`Goal`)... The elements of the list have to be *assignable to* the type of the function. The return type of the function has to be *assigned to* the type of the destination list, so you use `extends` there.

Comment: `Function<? super SRC, ? extends DEST>` . I understand the second parameter of the function. We are trying to insert `DEST`(and subclasses of `DEST`) objects into a `List<DEST>`. But I'm still a bit confused on the first parameter. The source list could be a `List<Goal>` or `List<Strategy>` or whatever. How are those two superclasses of the current `SRC`? I'm sorry if I seem stupid, I just am terrible with generic bounds. :(

Comment: Oh hold on, I think I get it. The function will take anything that is itself or a supertype of itself. It will take a `Goal`, for example, but it will also take a `PlanItem`. It then turns it into the `DEST` object, or a sublass of `DEST`, before adding it to the `List<DEST>`. Am I right?